# How does the Brita water filter pitcher "change filter" indicator work? What is that gold cylinder?

Tags: pcb

[Product link](https://a.co/d/i1oOuBJ)

I've taken apart the indicator. It is circled in blue:

[image]

Here is a photo of the PCB of the indicator with some de-soldered components:

[image]

I think the gold cylinder (circled in red) is somehow responsible for detecting orientation; it can detect when the lid is opened for refilling the pitcher and increment a count which is usef as a proxy for filter health.

There is what sounds like a loose ball rattling inside the gold cylinder.

Can anyone provide the technical name for that gold cylinder component and explain how this system works?

Comment: Tilt switch perhaps?

Comment: It is just a time, which counts work time. And I agree with user_1818839. It is cheap tilt switch.

Comment: the device counts number of times  the lid is opened ... the cylinder is a tilt switch ... an assumption is made that the pitcher is filled from completely empty to completely full everytime the lid is opened

Comment: The three of you have together answered the question in the comments.  Would one of you like to write a real answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The device signals when it is time to change the filter, so it has to detect how much water has passed through the filter.

Best guess is that the device counts number of times the lid is opened, because it makes no sense to detect any other event.

The cylinder is a tilt switch that detects the lid being opened.

There is no other sensor, so the device has to make an assumption that the pitcher is filled from completely empty to completely full everytime the lid is opened.